# How to call-out html code to other pages using javascript or other codes rather than re-writing the long code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a big problem here. I'm a beginner in programming and I was wondering if you could help me out in this little - or rather major problem that I'm having here. I'm running a blog and I got this "recently posted" section on the side bar which consists of all my recent posts. Here's an example of what my code looks like on the `<aside>` section:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is to just give you an idea of what my "recently posted" section code looks like. The actual code is very very long. So now the problem I have is that I have to copy and paste the same "long" code to all the pages that I want the "recently posted" list to show. Is the a way I can capture this code and invoke it on other pages using javascript or another code? It's just that when I change the content inside the list, I have to update the list on other pages too so that my site visitors can see my latest posts. You know, just like Wordpress. Excuse my grammar. Please help me!

Comment: It's possible with the help of PHP - just create a file and import it anywhere you want.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure where to begin other than telling you that you want to create reusable components.  Instead of statically coding your sidebar in a particular page, you want an html template that uses JavaScript to configure it for a particular page/application.  Are you using any server-side technology, such as php or .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website supports PHP I would recommend you to create a .php file with the code you want on every page for example:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Post Topic 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you include the php file on every page, and next time you only need to edit the php file and it would update on every page that include the file.
To include the php file in the html file use:

```
<?php include("filename.php");?>
```

Comment: I am planning on changing my web files extentions from html to php. But now the problem is that when I click on my links, I get an error...I'm sure it's because of the extention changing from html to php. Is there a way I can easily sort this problem out without having to change every link manually  from <a href="link.html">link name</a> to <a href="link.php">link name</a> ?

Comment: No you need to change the links manually but if you use a good text editor you can find and replace all .html to .php